# Issue in Parsing JSON response using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, json, ssjs

I have a JSON Response that I received after performing a HTTP POST call.

```
{
    "Status": 0,
    "Content": "{
        \"id\": \"73614a0d-39af-48a3-8b95-d221edc39eb7\",
        \"key\": \"aeb932a6-8883-d273-d99e-f9ee8a306305\",
        \"name\": \"test journey dipa\",
        \"lastPublishedDate\": \"2018-07-11T05:31:22\",
        \"description\": \"\",
        \"version\": 1,
        \"workflowApiVersion\" :1.0,
        \"createdDate\": \"2018-07-11T05:30:44.417\",
        \"modifiedDate\": \"2018-07-11T05:31:22.427\"
    }"
}
```

From this, I wanted to take the value of the name.

```
var val1 = Content.name;
Write(Stringify(val1));
```

I used the above code , but i got null value. What is the issue over the parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's string, you'll need to make it an actual JSON object/array by parsing it.

Here's the pattern I use:

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

  Platform.Load("Core","1");

  var debug = true;
  var ContentStr = response.Content; /* whatever is correct here for your case */
  var ContentJSONObj;

  try {

     ContentJSONObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(ContentStr);

  } catch (e) {

     Platform.Function.RaiseError("Could not parse JSON payload", true);

  }

  if (debug) {
   Write("<br>ContentJSONObj: " + Stringify(ContentJSONObj))
  }

  var name = ContentJSONObj.name ? ContentJSONObj.name : "";
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@name", name);

  if (debug) {
     Write("<br>name: " + name)
  }

</script>
%%=v(@name)=%%
```